# How to pass value from HTML Form to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to send the HTML form value as a `CURLOPT_FIELDS`. My HTML form:

```
<form class="form-response" method="POST" action="postform.php">
    <h2 class="form-response-heading">get Response</h2>
    <input name="phonenumber" class="form-control" type="text" autofocus="" required="" placeholder="phonenumber">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Get Response</button>
</form>
```

And currently my `postform.php` is:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.example.com/AccountDetails",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{ \"phonenumber\":\"6282818966317\", \"FullName\":\"Jenny Doe\" }",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json;charset=UTF8",
    "api-key: myapikeynumbers",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

I tried the HTML form will pass the value into the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{ \"phonenumber\":\"6282818966317\" }",

So far the `postform.php` will return the response if I add manually the phone number.  What I want to do is `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` will automatically get the value from the `phonenumber` input from the HTML form.

Comment: `"{ \"phonenumber\":\"" . $_POST['phonenumber'] . "\",...` should do. Was that what you where asking for?

Comment: Hi Jeff, Yes I want to get the form input into culrpost, i tried this but the response appear an error "responseCode":-2,"responseMessage":"Inputs are invalid."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the values in a variable and pass that variable.

```
//Somewhere up here, store the post data in a variable something like this:
$phone = $_POST['phonenumber'];
$fullName = $_POST['full_name'];

 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{ \"phonenumber\":\"" .$phone . "\", \"FullName\":\"" . $fullName . "\" }",
```

I find storing the input in variables allows you to work with them more easily. According to your comment above, you probably need to look at the documentation to see what the API you are connecting to expects and verify the input is valid before sending it.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming you are wanting to pass the first name dynamically as well. In that case, add a form filed to your html.

Comment: hi @jddev81, thanks for the suggestion, but i got an error response 
'Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): expected a value at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@526e4938; line: 1, column: 40]'
:(

Comment: @Bireon , I think I had a syntax error. See the edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jddev81, it's work now. Thanks for help.

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked. I would look into validating the form input before sending this. You can accomplish this with PHP but I think a better user experience would be doing so with Javascript.

Comment: Hi @jddev81, do you mean validating the form input based on the json data?

Comment: I mean be sure it is a valid format that is accepted by the API for the phone number and the name. Any input you send, you should be sure it is what the API is expecting to avoid errors.

Comment: Thanks @jddev81, I will implement the validation my plan is using the JavaScript. Thanks again for help and suggestions.

Comment: ... this needs escaping, for much the same reasons that you can't just insert variables in SQL queries, you need to escape those variables first. make it ```CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array("phonenumber"=>$phone,"FullName"=>$fullName))```
 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply pass all POSTed data on to `curl`?  It looks like you need to send `JSON` to your API endpoint, so:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($_POST),
```

Any field you include in your form with a `name` and `value` will be in `_POST`.  Just pass it on to `curl`.

If there are extra fields you need to send which are not in your form, just add them to the `_POST` array before sending, for eg:

```
$_POST['FullName'] = "Jenny Doe";

// ... rest of your code

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($_POST),
```

You should never try to manual construct `JSON`, it is too easy to make mistakes.  Just create your array and use the built in tools.